# How to simulate mouse and keyboard input to a specific program in c#

Tags: c#, input

Anyone know how to give mouse and keyboard input to a specific program WITHOUT Being focused, so i can make a program that programmatically simulate mouse and keyboard input only to that program and i can do other things without getting disturbed by that process, unlike java's Robot that simulate mouse and keyboard control and that program must be in focus and foreground.

Comment: Do all of the other usual methods, like SendMessage/Postmessage, give focus to the window?  Why do you need to do it without changing focus?  What would you do if that is impossible?

Comment: SendMessage should not require focus. It only requires a handle to the Process.

Answer (score 0):

AutoIt provides a DLL that you can add as a reference in your application. It exposes the `AutoItX3` object that is very versatile and can do all of what you're asking for.

See: https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/

Comment: but after i refer the dll, dll have AutoITX3, AutoITX3Class, and IAutoITX3, which one is should use and how? for example i want to click at point (30,50) in a window named "Window - Example" and still, no need to focus, and other example if i want to type "test" in a windows named "Window - Example" without focusing it also

Comment: @HansYulian You have to create an instance of the AutoItX3 object and call the methods that it provides.